# Cannot perform alter on 'Views' because it is an incompatible object type

Tags: sql-server

I try to alter the view in my database. But the system is throwing the following error.

> Msg 2010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure V******, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Cannot perform alter on 'dbo.V_**** because it is an incompatible object type.

I have dropped the view and created a fresh view then its worked. But I don't want to drop and create.

```sql
ALTER view [dbo].[V_***] as
 with
  L******* (
   LOC_ID,
   CLASS_ID,
   LOC_BARCODE,
   LOC_NAME,
   LOC_NAME_BASE,
   LOC_NAME_LAST,
   SORT_LEVEL,
   P_LOC_ID,
   DEL_FLAG,
   SEL_FLAG,
   OVER_CHECK_FLAG
  )
  as
  (
   select
    LOC_ID,
    CLASS_ID,
    LOC_BARCODE,
    cast(LOC_NAME as nvarchar(4000)) LOC_NAME,
    cast('' as nvarchar(4000)) LOC_NAME_BASE,
    LOC_NAME LOC_NAME_LAST,
    SORT_LEVEL,
    P_LOC_ID,
    DEL_FLAG,
    SEL_FLAG,
    OVER_CHECK_FLAG
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7239/transact-sql-using-with-in-create-view) can help

Comment: WAnt to alter the view not create

Comment: Does the view load into the View Designer in Management Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, my guess is that you already have an object with that name.

> Cannot perform alter on '' because it is an incompatible object type.

**Cause:** In sql server, we cannot alter one object to another object type likes:

1. Table to view or vice versa
2. Stored procedure to function or vice versa
3. Scalar function to tabled valued function or vice versa

Try the `ALTER view [dbo].[V_***]` with different name.

You can always check the views on your SQL Server prior creating the view via:

```
select Name 
  from sys.views 
 where name LIKE '%your_view_name%'
```